# Jasmine: Expecting Error to be Thrown in a Async Function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular2-services

I have an async function in my angular2 app for which I want to write a unit test. Imagine my function is like this:

```
myFunc(a: int): Promise<void> {
    if (a == 1)
        throw new Error('a should not be 1');

    let body = {
        value: a
    };
    return apiService.patch('/url/', JSON.stringify(body)).toPromise();
}
```

Now, I'm thinking of checking that if condition. I tried the following code; but, this test always fails since my code actually does not wait for any results:

```
it('should throw error if a = 1', () => {
    expect(() => {
        mySerivce.myFunc(1);
    }).toThrow(new Error('a should not be 1'));
})
```

I don't know how I should write unit tests for these types of logics...

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing 1 into your function? mySerivce.myFunc(1);

Comment: @ppham27 oops! Just added. Good catching!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use try catch.

This is what I came up with and it was also what was suggested on the Github issue tracker for jasmine.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1410

```ts
function double(a: number): Promise<number> {
   if (a === 1) {
       throw new Error('a should not be 1')
   }

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(resolve, 100, a * 2 )
   })
}

describe('test double', () => {
    it('should double any number but 1', async() => {
        const result = await double(2);
        expect(result).toBe(4)
    });

    it('should throw an error', async() => {
        let error;
        try {
            await double(1)
        } catch (e) {
            error = e;
        }
        const expectedError = new Error('a should not be 1');
        expect(error).toEqual(expectedError)

    })
});
```

I also wrote myself a little helper

```ts
async function unpackErrorForAsyncFunction(functionToTest: Function, ...otherArgs: any[]): Promise<Error> {
    let error;
    try {
        const result = await functionToTest(...otherArgs);
    } catch (e) {
        error = e;
    }
    return error;
}

function double(a: number): Promise<number> {
    if (a === 1) {
        throw new Error('a should not be 1')
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100, a * 2 )
    })
}

function times(a: number, b: number): Promise<number> {
    if (a === 1 && b === 2) {
        throw new Error('a should not be 1 and 2')
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100, a * b )
    })
}

describe('test times and double with helper', () => {
    it('double should throw an error with test helper', async() => {
        const result = await unpackErrorForAsyncFunction(double, 1);
        const expectedError = new Error('a should not be 1');

        expect(result).toEqual(expectedError)
    });

    it('times should throw an error with test helper', async() => {
        const result = await unpackErrorForAsyncFunction(times, 1, 2);
        const expectedError = new Error('a should not be 1 and 2');

        expect(result).toEqual(expectedError)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 41):

Nowadays jasmine (3.3+) supports this natively:

https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/async-matchers.html

```
it('should...', async () => {
  await expectAsync(myService.myFunc(1))
    .toBeRejectedWith(new Error('a should not be 1'));
});
```

Comment: I think that is the best way to do that. It works well for me and is very clear!

Comment: I love the answer however It does not seem to work for me. I am testing a function that is returning a new promise. Inside the promise is where it throws the error before resolve or reject hits. Any ideas? The error will come out 'Type Error ../filenameHere.ts'

Comment: This should be the answer.!

Answer (score -3):

You can assert if a method throws an error using a spy:

```
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;
it('should...', () => {
 (mySerivce.myFunc as Spy).and.Callthrough();
 mySerivce.myFunc(1);
 expect(mySerivce.myFunc).toThrow();
});
```

Optionally use `fakeASync` to solve "racecondition" trouble.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I assume that you meant to write "it" instead of first "except". Still, your approach does not seem to fix my problem. myService.myFunc().then is called when the function has been completely run. In my case, it is going to throw an exception. So, it will never come into the then block casuing "Async callback function not called within the default jasmine timeout" or something like that.

Comment: where exactly did you call the **myFunc(1)**?

Comment: I thought that was implied. My bad :)